# SQL Server Dynamic Order By Performance Issue

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, sql-order-by, case-statement, sqlperformance

**1. Here's the Procedure (the largest table has about 1M rows) to retrieve records**

```
Create Procedure GetallTransctions(@Pagesize,@CurrentPage,@SortColumn,@SortDirection)
AS
Begin

select TOP (@PageSize) * from (

  Select Top ((@PageSize*CurrentPage)+@PageSize) * from TransactionDetails where 
  TransactionType ='Pay'--Few more conditions
  Order By 
  case when @SortColumn= 'CustomerName' and @SortDirection= 'ASC' 
  then CustomerName end asc, 
  case when @SortColumn= 'CustomerName' and @SortDirection= 'DESC' 
  then CustomerName end desc

  ) a
```

Above procedure performance is good until row count is less than 1M. When records size keep increasing its take around 40 secs to execute. If i hard-code the Order by like this

```
Order By 
  CustomerName ASC
```

The query takes 3-5 secs to execute but i can't hard-code the sorting columns. Is Case statement in order by clause affect the performance ? Any solution/query.

**2.Above procedure paging is implemented. So let say i need to pick records at range of 70000 - 70010. We apply sorting based on parameter value fetches 0-70010 and we take top 10 records. instead apply sorting and fetch only 70000 - 70010. Is there any other way?**

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that the SQL optimizer doesn't recognize that an index can be used for the sorting.

The solution is to use dynamic SQL.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
select TOP (@PageSize) * from (
  Select Top ((@PageSize*CurrentPage)+@PageSize) * from TransactionDetails where 
  TransactionType =''Pay'' --Few more conditions
';

if @SortColumn = 'CustomerName' and @SortDirection = 'ASC' 
  set @sql = @sql + ' order by CustomerName asc';
else if  @SortColumn = 'CustomerName' and @SortDirection = 'DESC' 
  set @sql = @sql + ' order by CustomerName desc';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '@Pagesize', @Pagesize);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

This will recompile the query each time it is run (incurring overhead).  But, it should also quickly get the data you are looking for if the sort can use an index.

Also, in SQL Server 2012+, you can use the `offset`/`fetch` clauses, which are better for paging.

Comment: intially i used dynamic query but we're change into precompiled query. Is there any other solution without dynamic query?

Comment: @Siva . . . The solution would be to repeat the query multiple times `if @sortColumn = . . . begin select . . . order by CustomerName asc` end else if . . . `. I don't recommend repeating the query.  It becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: What is the kind of overhead involved in recompiling a dynamic stored proc? I know typically it depends, but generally expectation would be a few ms / 100's ms / or >1 sec? Just trying to get some ballpark idea, before rewriting a complex sql (hardcoded ORDER BYs, ~500ms to execute). Thanks!

Comment: It should be less than running the query